# Toddler sleeping with head covered

Tags: toddler, bedtime

My son is 21 months. He can sleep with and without blankets no problem. But when he has any blankets I usually allow multiple hospital like baby blankets. If he isn't snuggling to them then they are laid next to him. In exception of one. He has to have one blanket cover his head when he goes to sleep. He won't fight over me moving it but I'm concerned if I need to real worry or if it's just a "him" kinda thing.

Comment: I have been Googling it and the only things I've found are that (under 12 months a sleep sack is more advised than a blanket) that mostly it's the mums who don't like it. They worry and don't like that it makes the child sweaty. I found nothing about it being dangerous -- it sounds fairly normal. I am commenting rather than answering because I did not parent a child through this stage.

Comment: My little one has been doing the same thing since we started letting her have a blanket, around 18 months.  She's 29 months now, still covers her face to sleep every night.  We look at the video monitor and she'll be completely sprawled out across her bed, with no blanket covering anything except her face.

Comment: I have done this all my life because I have Photophobia. Maybe consider if this is not the underlying cause.

Answer (score 3):

I would not worry too much about it. My son did roughly the same but a little older, around 3 or 4, and with a full comforter. I'd go pull it down after he was asleep and his hair was all sweaty but otherwise he was fine. He still likes to have the blankets up to his neck even when they seem way too warm to me. His siblings mostly kick them all off. I had weirder sleeping habits when I was a kid myself. So I'd say it's just his thing.

If you haven't done that already, you could try leaving a night light. Perhaps he's scared and feels safer under the blankets.

Comment: or is particularly light sensitive and blocking it if there is already a night light.

Comment: or just likes to be covered up when he's sleeping.  I still cover up.  He's large enough to uncover himself, and will do so if he gets uncomfortable.